# Bluemix Compose Postgres ElasticSearch and RabbitMQ

Tags: ibm-cloud, network-traffic, compose-db

If I run my Java application on Bluemix PaaS (Cloud Foundry runtime) and I bind a Compose public service (I need Postgres, ElasticSearch and RabbitMQ), does the traffic between my application and the Compose service go on public internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an application on the public Bluemix (in US South, United Kingdom or Sydney region), when you bind one of Compose’s DBaaS offerings you continue to use the "external" service, so the answer to your question is yes: the traffic goes on public network.